# How do I run a loading animation before page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

Exactly like this one - http://www.solasie.com/en/.
Also I want the animation to load every time and just not the first time.

Here are the related questions.

[Display an animation while loading a page using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658270/display-an-animation-while-loading-a-page-using-jquery?rq=1) and

[How to load animated gif before Flash load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449399/how-to-load-animated-gif-before-flash-load?rq=1)

EDIT 1

I tried using the following code. Its showing an error.

```
<html >
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loading">
<img src="counting30ll6.gif" > 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#loading').delay(10000).queue(function(){ $(this).hide();$(this).dequeue(); });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the code that you've already tried to work with, so that somebody can improve it.

Comment: I am only a beginner. I don't know how to code for this effect. I want to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this animation is running after the page loads.
Wrap all your animation code into a function and then bind it on onLoad event. This will make the impression that you want.

**EDIT**
Here is a little jsfiddle that might give you some direction.

jsfiddle.net/gBspY/